# How to get auth token automatically in laravel and vue?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-vue

I am using laravel passport for authentication in my laravel and vue.js ecommerce project.

After successful login, I want to redirect user to his/her dashboard.

Here is the vue dashboard page:

```
<template>
  <div class="content-center">
    <h1>Dashboard my account</h1>
    <p>
        {{userData.name}}
    </p>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import Axios from "axios";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      userData: "",
      authToken: ""
    }
  },
  async beforeMount() {
    let res = await Axios.get("http://localhost:8000/api/user-details", {
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + this.authToken, 
        Accept: 'application/json'
      },
       
    });
     this.userData = res.data;
     
    //  let token = await Axios.get("http://localhost:8000/api/user-login")
    //   this.authToken = res.data.data.auth_token
    //let res = await Axios.get("http://localhost:8000/api/user-details");
    
  },
};
</script>
```

Everytime I login to different user accounts, I have to set the value of authToken manually copy and pasting from Postman. I want to set this token automatically when a user logs in. How can I do this ?

Here is my api controller:

```
class AuthApiController extends Controller
{
    public function userDetails(){
        return auth()->user();
    }
    public function login(Request $request){
            
        $user = User::where('email',$request->email)->first();
        if (!$user || !Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
            return response()->json([
                'success'=>false,
                'data'=>[],
                'message'=>'Login failed',
                'errors'=>[]
            ]);
        }else{
            return response()->json([
                'success'=>true,
                'data'=>['user'=> $user, 'auth_token' =>  $user->createToken('AuthToken')->accessToken],
                'message'=>'Login success',
                'errors'=>[]
            ]);
           
        }
        
    }
```

**Updates:**

dashboard.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="content-center">
    <h1>Dashboard my account</h1>
    <p>
        {{userData.name}}
    </p>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import Axios from "axios";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      userData: "",
      authToken: ""
    }
  },
  async beforeMount() {
    let res = await Axios.get("http://localhost:8000/api/user-details", {
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + this.authToken, 
        Accept: 'application/json'
      },
       
    });
     this.userData = res.data;
     
     let token = await $api.get("http://localhost:8000/api/user-login")
      this.authToken = res.data.data.auth_token
    
    
  },
};
</script>
```

**Picture:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLGgX.png)

What should I write to import api.js ?

import $api from ./../api.js  **or**  anything else ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can store your token in LocalStorage. And whenever you request just get it from the local storage and pass it to the request header.

If you are using Axios then you can use `interceptors` and just intercept your every request and pass token in the header.

Step 1.

Create a file called `api.js` or you can call it whatever you want.

Step 2.

Create an Axios instance in the `api.js` file.

```
import axios from 'axios';

// Put your backend url here
export const API_URL = `http://localhost:5000/api`

const $api = axios.create({
    withCredentials: true,
    baseURL: API_URL
})

$api.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
    return config;
})


export default $api;
```

Step 3: Where ever you are using Axios use this exported instance so in your component you would do like this:

```
const userdata = await $api.get("http://localhost:8000/api/user-details");
```

Here you can see, we are using the `$api` Axios instance which we created in the `api.js` file instead of `Axios` direct.

Add also don't forget to store your token in your local storage when you getting that.

```
localStorage.setItem('token', "Your token goes here...");
```

I hope this will give you an idea.

This way, Token will be sent with every request automatically, if it exists in the localStorage.

UPDATE:

```
<template>
  <div class="content-center">
    <h1>Dashboard my account</h1>
    <p>
        {{userData.name}}
    </p>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
// import Axios from "axios";
   import $api from 'put relative path of your api.js file'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      userData: "",
      authToken: ""
    }
  },
  async beforeMount() {
    let res = await $api.get("/user-details");
     this.userData = res.data;
     
     let res = await $api.get("/user-login")
      localStorage.setItem('token', res.data.data.auth_token);        
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: where is the local storage located ? What is local storage ?

Comment: Local storage is located in every browser.

Comment: Its difficult to understand. How can I call the api directly without using api.js ?

Comment: you will have to import it in component. 
`import $api from 'your api.js file path here'` Then use.

Comment: I have updated my post. Please check if its correct.

Comment: You don't need to use the complete domain in the request since we are setting the BASE URL in the `api.js` file. Just do: `et token = await $api.get("/user-login")`

Also, do this for all other requests.

Comment: And import $api, you did not import it

Comment: And where should I puth this "localStorage.setItem('token', "Your token goes here...");"

Comment: After you receive that.  After this line : `this.authToken = res.data.data.auth_token` Don't store it in `this.authToken` instead save it in localstorage

Comment: Please kindly show me an example and sorry to disturb you again and again.

Comment: Not working. Not getting the value of this {{userData.name}}

Comment: Check console and see if if request is getting send. or any error in console

Comment: I think there is an issue here "res.data.data.auth_token"

Comment: [Vue warn]: Error in beforeMount hook (Promise/async): "Error: Request failed with status code 401"